# How much HTML Encrypted Media Extensions (EME) is reliable?

Tags: html, security, eme

We are implementing HTML5 EME for our video-based web page. As you know, EME prevents downloading video from a server. Accordingly, the video files it so important for us and we want to prevent stealing these files.

By implementation, we have an API, servers, etc that leading it's not that much secure.

Therefore, what is the security risk of HTML Encrypted Media Extensions? Is it reliable enough?

Comment: What will keep me from recording the video from my screen?

Comment: @GaborLengyel We'll add a watermark system. If someone shares videos we know which user did.

Comment: Hi @M.Rostami, is it possible to implement EME without internet like in local lan environment ?

Comment: @krishna Why not? But you may need to create whole the system by yourself. In addition, there are some good open-source repositories.

Comment: hi @M.Rostami ,  I want to use videojs-contrib-eme, and what other extra components are required for full implementation ,which can be done with open-source repositories?